# Setting Environment variables in Windows 10, to be able to run Python from cmd

Tags: windows, windows-10, python, environment-variables

I want to be able to run python from cmd prompt, so I have set an environment variable name "Python" with a variable value as the path to the directory the file is in (python.exe). I then close with OK (though I do not understand why "Apply" is greyed out). I run cmd, and typing python produces: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

If I type "set" then Python is listed as a variable.
I am logged on as administrator, and I have read the previous discussions on setting environment variables. Can anyone please advise me where I am going wrong? thanks

Comment: You add the *directory* that `python` is in, to the variable named `PATH`, which contains multiple directories separated by semicolons (win10 has a nice editor for it). You don't create a new variable with a different name.

Comment: In addition, depending on the process (cmd being one of them) you will need to reboot in order to reflect the change.

Comment: and actually if you install python - newest versions, I think, by default add it to path, but for older you have to tick box for this ... and don't have to add manually to path anything, just do proper installation.

Comment: Thanks, that works.  I have only just installed python 3.6 and it didn't add it's path into path.

Comment: Yeah, just install Python and it should do it for you.  Works with 2.7 just fiine.